# hh:mm:ss to time.Time while parsing from JSON in Go

Tags: json, go, parsing, struct, time

I have a struct that I can't change and an array of these structs in a separate JSON file.
I could have parsed data from JSON file easily, but there are mismatched types in same fields:

(main.go)

```
import "time"

type SomeType struct { 
    name string    `json: "name"`
    time time.Time `json: "someTime"`
}
```

(someData.json)

```
[
    {
        "name": "some name",
        "someTime": "15:20:00"
    },

    {
        "name": "some other name",
        "someTime": "23:15:00"
    }
]
```

If "time" field was a type of a string, I would simply use json.Unmarshal and parse all of the data from json into []SomeType, but since types mismatch, I can't find a way to do it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the UnmarshalJSON method to your struct

```
type SomeType struct {
    Name string    `json:"name"`
    Time time.Time `json:"someTime"`
}

func (st *SomeType) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    type parseType struct {
        Name string `json:"name"`
        Time string `json:"someTime"`
    }
    var res parseType
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &res); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    parsed, err := time.Parse("15:04:05", res.Time)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    now := time.Now()
    st.Name = res.Name
    st.Time = time.Date(now.Year(), now.Month(), now.Day(), parsed.Hour(), parsed.Minute(), parsed.Second(), 0, now.Location())
    return nil
}
```

[GoPlay](https://goplay.tools/snippet/ptIFIzj0tDR)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should define a custom time type, with a custom unmarshaller as follows:

```golang
type CustomTime struct {
        time.Time
}

func (t *CustomTime) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
        formattedTime, err := time.Parse(`"15:04:05"`, string(b))
        t.Time = formattedTime
        return err
}
```

And have another struct, which is basically the exact struct you have, instead it uses your custom time type rather than the original struct which uses `time.Time`:

```golang
type SameTypeWithDifferentTime struct {
        Name          string       `json:"name"`
        SomeTime      CustomTime   `json:"someTime"`
}

func (s SameTypeWithDifferentTime) ToOriginal() SomeType {
        return SomeType {
                Name: s.Name,
                SomeTime: s.SomeTime.Time,
        }
}
```

The rest of the process is pretty straight forward, you just deserialize your json to the new type, and use `ToOriginal()` receiver function to convert it to your original struct. Another point to mention here is that your not exporting your struct fields.